# correct preposition before 'environment'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the following sentence is correct?

1.Coal mines constitute a major percentage of the sources which cause damage on the environment.

2.Coal mines constitute a major percentage of the sources which cause damage to the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it's **damage to [something]**.

If it's spatial, you can cause **damage on/under/near the surface of [something]** (on top/on the side/on the wall/under the stairs).